# Show hat count in user card (next to badges)

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, winter-bash-2014, user-card

I've been having tons of fun with the hats! But I have a complaint:

**There is no way to show off how many hats I have.**

Even more irksome I have to go into people profiles to see if they have more hats than me, which means I have to go in and out of pages.

**Why not display a hat count with the badges?**

> [image]

Comment: And actually I like this proposal. Just this is the place for badges, maybe hatz should be after the name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be nice if they could do this. Only have it visible to people participating in Winter Bash though. There's not much room on the right of the user display pic, so maybe just put it on the left side where space is available.

I like to see how many hats people have, and it would be nice to see this information without having to click on their profile each time.

Answer (score 20):

> If I have learned anything from the Internet, it is this: [be very, very careful when you put a number next to someone's name](http://blog.codinghorror.com/for-a-bit-of-colored-ribbon/). **Because people will do whatever it takes to make that number go up**.

<sup>- Jeff Atwood, [Coding Horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/because-reading-is-fundamental-2/)</sup>

People are already concerned about users abusing the sites just to earn hats. Putting a fancy little number next to their name will only make that problem worse.

Comment: So [below](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b122R.png) instead of next to makes all the difference?

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Far less people will view your profile than will view questions or answers written by you.

Comment: What about the number of times a user was suspended? ;)

Answer (score 4):

This looked like an interesting challenge, so I wrote a userscript that will show you other people's hat-count.

Partial screenshot:

> [image: Added hat counts]

To use it:

1. First, **install Greasemonkey** (or Scriptish) if you are using **Firefox**.
   or
2. **Install Tampermonkey** if you are using **Google Chrome**.
   then
3. [Click here to install the userscript from GitHub](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/d54dfda1c9ba7434209d/raw/hatoverflow.user.js).

For more information, or issue reports, see [the script's entry on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/5056/hat-overflow-show-number-of-winterbash-hats-at-a-glance).

Comment: Thanks man... :D I think you've earned 50 rep :D (I'll award it after the five days though.)

Comment: Okay, and here is you 50

Comment: Updated the script for 2015 (fixed busted graphic),  Reload if you don't have version 2.4.