# Is it possible to see who has what hats quickly?

Tags: support, winter-bash

I want to be able to quickly find who has what hats, but I don't know if it is possible. Is there a specific search? Or are mod tools required? Any ideas or know-how?

Comment: This user-script could be moded to show what hats as well as how many: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245841/262509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it with [**Leaderboard**](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) and once you entered the particular site use the searchbox to find the user. that's it!